# Compile std::regex_iterator with gcc

Tags: c++, regex, linker, g++, c++11

I can create .o file with *g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++0x*, but cant link it, got next errors:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<char const*, char, std::regex_traits<char> >::regex_iterator(char const*, char const*, std::basic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> > const&, std::bitset<11u>)'
test.cpp:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<char const*, char, std::regex_traits<char> >::regex_iterator()'
```

Code:

```
#include <regex> 
#include <iostream> 

#include <string.h>

typedef std::regex_iterator<const char *> Myiter; 
int main() 
{ 
    const char *pat = "axayaz"; 
    Myiter::regex_type rx("a"); 
    Myiter next(pat, pat + strlen(pat), rx); 
    Myiter end; 


    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: Which version of GCC? `<regex>` isn't actually implemented up to and inluding 4.6.2. Also, why not use `std::cregex_iterator` instead?

Comment: have you considered using the boost regex libraries? Both boost::regex and boost::xpressive are fully functional.

Comment: i know man, i used this staff, but for now i cant..

Comment: This might help someone: Don't be fooled if you think you have a regex implementation in gcc 4.7.1. Look closely at the content of regex.h and you'll see it full of TODO entries and unimplemented functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The GNU C++ standard library supports `<regex>`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x), but [not until version 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631).  (The headers were present in earlier versions, but were unusable.)

The other compilers don't support it, as far as I can see.

You can use a [different library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) if you use an older GCC.

Comment: Both MSVC and Clang support <regex>. Actually regex is pretty much the only part of C++11 where GCC lags behind other compilers.