# How to use stringstream to separate comma separated strings

Tags: c++, tokenize, stringstream

I've got the following code:

```
std::string str = "abc def,ghi";
std::stringstream ss(str);

string token;

while (ss >> token)
{
    printf("%s\n", token.c_str());
}
```

The output is:

> abc
> def,ghi

So the `stringstream::>>` operator can separate strings by space but not by comma. Is there anyway to modify the above code so that I can get the following result?

> **input**: "abc,def,ghi"
>
> **output**:
> abc
> def
> ghi

Comment: [Splitting a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c) contains everything a human should know about splittin strings in C++

Comment: Second answer in the duplicate target also answers this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/2527795

Answer (score 339, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string input = "abc,def,ghi";
std::istringstream ss(input);
std::string token;

while(std::getline(ss, token, ',')) {
    std::cout << token << '\n';
}
```

> abc
>   def
>   ghi

Comment: Why do you guys always use std:: and full namespaces instead of using namespace? Is there specific reasoning for this? I just always find it as a very noisy and had-to-read syntax.

Comment: @DmitryGusarov It's a habit and a good practice. It doesn't matter in short examples, but `using namespace std;` is bad in real code. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: ah, so it sounds like the problem caused by c++ ability to have a method outside of a class. And probably this is why it never lead to problem in C# / Java. But is it a good practice to have a method outside of a class? Modern languages like Kotlin don't even allow static methods.

Comment: In Kotlin, you can declare functions inside `companion object` inside classes which are basically static methods.

Comment: This is short and readable which is great, but is this the fastest way to do it in c++?

Comment: How do you adapt this answer to skipping white spaces e.g., if `std::string input = "abc, def, ghi";` I want to get rid of the white spaces when parsing by commas with getline.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string input = "abc,def,   ghi";
    std::istringstream ss(input);
    std::string token;
    size_t pos=-1;
    while(ss>>token) {
      while ((pos=token.rfind(',')) != std::string::npos) {
        token.erase(pos, 1);
      }
      std::cout << token << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: This code isn't correct, it generates `abcdef \n ghi` as output.