# Shared two project files

Tags: c++

I have string that I would like cut to substrings according `0x1d` cahr delimiter. How to tell `istringstream` that it must extract chars dosed according `0x1d` delimiter during `>>` operation?

```
string s("Somewhere"+string(1,0x1d)+"down"+string(1,0x1d)+"the"+string(1,0x1d)+"road");

istringstream iss(s);

do
{
    string sub;

    iss >> sub;
    cout << "Substring: " << sub << endl;
} while (iss);
```

Comment: You could use `std::getline(iss, sub, '\x1d')` rather than `operator>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You get your respond [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719538/how-to-use-stringstream-to-separate-comma-separated-strings)

From @jrok

```
std::string input = "abc,def,ghi";
std::istringstream ss(input);
std::string token;

while(std::getline(ss, token, ',')) {
    std::cout << token << '\n';
}
```