# How to read CSV file with C++

Tags: c++, parsing, csv

I have a csv file with the following information on each line:

```
John,Doe,17
```

The ifstream object name is inFile and I tried:

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
int age;
inFile >> firstName >> "," >> lastName >> "," >> age
```

However, clearly, i cannot do `>> "," >>`

How do I correctly get those values and use them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
int age;
getline(inFile, firstName, ',');
getline(inFile, lastName, ',');
inFile >> age;
```

If you want to keep it consistent, you can use getline(inFile, ..., ',') for all data, then use std::stoi to convert age to integer. Or you can use getline(inFile, wholeline), and then use sscanf on the wholeline.

Comment: string tempVariable;
    getline(inFile, tempVariable);
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    char comma;
    float age;
    
    while(inFile >> firstName >> comma >> lastName >> comma >> age {

Do you know why it never enters this loop? I use getline() to skip past the first line

Comment: `inFile >> firstName >> dummy >> lastName >> dummy >> age;` - this doesn't work - `>>` to a `std::string` consumes input until the next whitespace character or end-of-stream, so `"John,Doe,17"` ends up in `firstName`.

Comment: @D.Lin ah I didn't notice you don't have space before comma.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a stringstream and read each line into the stream using the comma as a delimiter.
See: [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719538/how-to-use-stringstream-to-separate-comma-separated-strings)

Comment: The thing is my first line is the headers such as "first, last, age", how would I take that into consideration to not read that line then?

Comment: How about skipping first line?

Comment: I'm hesitant to expand on my answer as I feel that it's more beneficial for one to experiment and work out the problem at hand, provided some guidance, as opposed to offering step-by-step instructions on what to do. With that said, concerning skipping a line, you don't have to do anything with a line when you read it (hint).

Comment: stringstream is not necessary because the infile is an istream and can be used the same way as stringstream mostly