# C++ Reading from File issue

Tags: c++, string, file-io

So i'm trying to read a series of strings from a file, separated by the tab character, then store them into a struct. The problem i'm having is that two of these strings contain space(s), heck one is a full blown sentence. So the usual (file >>) operation won't work. I have an idea how I can do it but it's wholly inefficient. Any ideas how i can do this?

Sample Data: Book noun. A collection of pages, written or blank.

This is the output i want:
Book noun. A collection of pages, written or blank.

This is the output i'm getting:
Book noun. A

This is my code so far:

```
void readFile(string filename)
{
    Node::Word fw;
    try
    {
        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in);
        if (file.fail())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error reading files!");
        }
        string word, description, pos;
        while (file >> word >> pos >> description)
        {
            fw.word = word;
            fw.partofspeech = pos;
            fw.meaning = description;
            insertElement(fw);
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error & e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue and not an unintended, undesirable feature?

Comment: `>>` reads exactly one whitespace delimited token from the input stream. Since `description` is at the end of the line, you may be able to get away with reading it with `std::getline`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719538/how-to-use-stringstream-to-separate-comma-separated-strings

Comment: So your `,` looks like a `.`, but same same.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe thanks that solved it.