# comma separated stringstream error. it also separates '-'

Tags: c++, tokenize, stringstream

The following is a set of data which I want to save in an array, struct using C++.

```
3110,300,15500,1,2017-11-29,8835,010-9033-1234
3110,396,530,1,2017-11-29,8835,010-9033-1234
3110,401,450,2,2017-11-29,8835,010-9033-1234
```

I used the following help to do so.
[How to use stringstream to separate comma separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719538/how-to-use-stringstream-to-separate-comma-separated-strings)
But I encountered two problems. Dates are saved as a:

```
2017
```

and phone numbers are saved as:

```
10
```

Instead, I wish to save them both as strings.

```
2017-11-29
010-9033-1234
```

Below is the code I made:

```
while (fileIN.good()) {
    while (getline(fileIN, lineA)) {
        cout << lineA << endl;
        istringstream ss(lineA); colA = 0;
        while (getline(ss, token, ',')) {
            if (colA = 0) { Data[rowA].price = stoi(token); cout << Data[rowA].price << endl; }
            else if (colA = 1) { Data[rowA].goods_seq = stoi(token); cout << Data[rowA].goods_seq << endl;}
            else if (colA = 2) { Data[rowA].goods_unit_price = stoi(token); cout << Data[rowA].goods_unit_price << endl;}
            else if (colA = 3) { Data[rowA].ea = stoi(token); cout << Data[rowA].ea << endl;}
            else if (colA = 4) { Data[rowA].want_date = token; cout << Data[rowA].want_date <<endl;}
            else if (colA = 5) { Data[rowA].member_seq = stoi(token); cout << Data[rowA].member_seq << endl;}
            else if (colA = 6) { Data[rowA].shipping_cellphone = token; cout << Data[rowA].shipping_cellphone << endl;}
            colA++;
        }
        rowA++;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `==` to do comparison

Comment: Compiling with `-Wall` will alert you to possible issues like this.

Comment: can u be a little more specific about where to place ==

Comment: oh my god... of course it should be ==.!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem you need to do `==` this occurs on `if (colA = 0)` which should be `if (colA == 0)`

Hope this helps