# Stringstream delimeter

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stream

I am parsing a CSV file, which has a known structure of `string,int,int,double`.

I am writing a function that parses a CSV file line-by-line.  I am trying to design it so that it looks something like this:

```
void foo(const string& csvline){
  std::stringstream csvStream(csvline);
  std::string s; int i1; int i2; double d;
  csvline >> s;
  csvline >> i1;
  csvline >> i2;
  csvline >> d;
}
```

Is there a way to do this for CSV files?

I know that if they were separated by spaces, this will work out of the box. But what about for a CSV file (or an arbitrary delimiter, for that matter)?

Comment: There are ways to do it, for example [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can use an arbitrary character as delimiter, not only newline. ***However*** I really don't recommend you implementing your own CSV parser. Error handling (which is always needed) is not very trivial. And generic CSV files have *many* corner and special cases that makes a simple parser using `std::getline` impossible to use. Please try to find an existing library that handles it for you instead.

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719538/how-to-use-stringstream-to-separate-comma-separated-strings]

Comment: This is just for me, I want to get better at parsing and working with streams.  I looked into `std::getline` but It always writes to a string doesnt it? I want my code to look as above, is there a way to do this or am i searching for a unicorn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot specify a delimiter with `operator>>`. Use `std::getline()` to read a delimited value into a temp `std::string`, then use a `std::istringstream` to parse the string.

```
void foo(const std::string& csvline)
{
    std::istringstream csvStream(csvline);
    std::string s, tmp;
    int i1, i2;
    double d;

    std::getline(csvStream, s, ',');

    std::getline(csvStream, tmp, ',');
    std::istringstream(tmp) >> i1;

    std::getline(csvStream, tmp, ',');
    std::istringstream(tmp) >> i2;

    std::getline(csvStream, tmp);
    std::istringstream(tmp) >> d;
}
```