# collecting pattern elements in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, iterator, pattern-matching

I need to collect elements from a string that match some pattern. For example, let's have the following URI fragment:

```
std::string uri = "/api/customer/123/order/456/total";
```

That is supposed to be matched by the following pattern:

```
std::string pattern = "/api/customer/:customerNum:/order/:orderNum:/total";
```

When analyzing that pattern, I want to collect the "variables" in it, ie substrings starting and ending with a colon. The following snippet (adapted from  [Split a string using C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435385/split-a-string-using-c11)) almost does the job:

```
std::set<std::string> patternVariables(const std::string &uriPattern)
{
    std::regex re(":([^:]+):");            // find a word surrounded by ":"

    std::sregex_token_iterator
    first ( uriPattern.begin(), uriPattern.end(), re),
    last;

    std::set<std::string> comp = {first, last};

    return comp;
}
```

The problem with that snippet is that it collects the variables including the ":" markers. What would be an idiomatic way to collect the variables *without* the colons (ie the `\1` in the matches, not the matches themselves)? I can manually iterate over the regexp matches and accumulate the matches in a loop, but I suspect there might be something more elegant similar to the `{first, last}` expression.

Assuming my context is clear, any comment taking it into account is welcome too:

- a better convention on marking variables in my pattern
- suggestions for better regex
- forward thinking about the next step in the workflow: matching a pattern to an actual URI returning a map of variables with their values (including patterns where the same variable(s) might appear several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I should remove my question altogether. The class `regex_token_iterator` has already anticipated that need. The idea is to use the optional 4th parameter to its constructor thus:

```
std::sregex_token_iterator
first ( uriPattern.begin(), uriPattern.end(), re, 1),
last;
```

The `1` means "I am interested in the matches 1st subexpression". The default value of `0` means "I am interested in the matches", and `-1` means "I am interested in the text between the matches".

(other comments still welcome).

Comment: Leave your question (and answer) in. It is good information for others with that same problem.