# how to populate vector from text file with two columns C++

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ and am trying to create a vector of points in a 2d plane read from a textfile. To do this I first create a struct consisting of two values (x,y) called point. Then a vector of these points called vec. However I am unsure of how to populate the struct data when the textfile is in three columns! The first column is just an index for the points, the second column is the x data and the third is the y data. I don't know the size of vec so I try to use `push_back()` Here is what I have so far.

```
    int main(){

        struct point{
 std::vector<x> vec_x;
 std::vector<y> vec_y;
    };

    std::vector<point> vec;
    vec.reserve(1000);
    push_back();

    ifstream file;
    file.open ("textfile.txt");
        if (textfile.is_open()){


/* want to populate x with second column and y with third column */
        }
        else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
```

Where the comment is I have the following;

```
while( file  >> x ) 
vec.push_back (x);


while( file  >> y ) 
vec.push_back (y);
```

Apologies if this is very simple, but it isn't to me! Posted below is an example of the txt file with only 6 points.

```
0 131 842
1 4033 90
2 886 9013490
3 988534 8695
4 2125 10
5 4084 474
6 863 25
```

**EDIT**

```
while (file >> z >> x >> y){

    struct point{
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    std::vector<point> vec;
    vec.push_back (x);
    vec.push_back (y);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the normal input operator `>>` in a loop:

```
int x, y;  // The coordinates
int z;     // The dummy first value

while (textfile >> z >> x >> y)
{
    // Do something with x and y
}
```

As for the structure, I suggest a little different approach:

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Then have a vector of structures:

```
std::vector<point> points;
```

In the loop, create a `point` instance, initialize its `x` and `y` member, then push it back into the `points` vector.

Note that the above code have almost no kind of error checking or fault tolerance. If there is an error in the file, more specifically if there is a problem with the format (for example one extra number in one line, or a number to little) then the code above will not be able to handle it. For that you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the whole line, put it into a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and read into the `x` and `y` variables from the string stream.

---

Putting it all together, the simple example of working code (without handling of invalid input) would then be something like

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// Defines the point structure
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    // A collection of points structures
    std::vector<point> points;

    // Open the text file for reading
    std::ifstream file("textfile.txt");

    // The x and y coordinates, plus the dummy first number
    int x, y, dummy;

    // Read all data from the file...
    while (file >> dummy >> x >> y)
    {
        // ... And create a point using the x and y coordinates,
        // that we put into the vector
        points.push_back(point{x, y});
    }

    // TODO: Do something with the points
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am still struggling with this however. I have edited the question, could you tell me if I am on the correct track? cheers!

Comment: @AngusTheMan A little yes, but also a lot of no. Please see my updated answer for a simple example program.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Read a line using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
2. Split the string for white spaces as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435385/split-a-string-using-c11)
3. push every element to your vectors.
4. repeat for next line until the end of the file