# C++ finding a value using find_if

Tags: c++, lambda, stl

I am trying to find if a string **words** contains any **instruction** form **machine_opTable**, a vector of pair-string,int.

What should my lambda function look like in find_if ?
If you have any other approach, please let me know.

As of now, my code looks like ...

```
# define RX 4
# define RR 2

...

vector < pair <string, int> > machine_opTable = { {"L", RX},
                                                  { "A", RX},
                                                  {"ST", RX}
                                                };

words = " L 1, SMB1";

string inMachineop;
for ( auto instruction: words){

    inMachineop = find_if ( begin(machine_opTable), end(machine_opTable), [] (const pair<string,int>& p) { return  ( p.first == instruction ? p.first : "NOTFOUND"); });

}
```

I would love to return iterator pointing to that pair... Please show me how it's done.

Thank you.

Comment: [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) takes a predicate – a truth-valued function – and returns an iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return value from `find_if` according to reference is

> An iterator to the first element in the range for which `pred` does not return false.

`pred` is your lambda and it must return bool value.
If you want to use `instruction` in your lambda, you have to capture this variable

```
[instruction] (const pair<string,int>& p) { return  p.first == instruction; }
```

and the call of `find_if` when we know it returns iterator looks as follows

```
auto it = find_if ( begin(machine_opTable), end(machine_opTable), [instruction] (const pair<string,int>& p) { return  p.first == instruction; });
if (it != machine_opTable.end())
{
    // access to found pair
}
else 
    ; // pair not found
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

I see a bug here:

```
for ( auto instruction: words){
```

You iterate by characters, not by words here. You need to split by space first. Try to use this code for that task https://stackoverflow.com/a/27511119/9187525

Bugs related to `find_if()` was explained by others :)