# C++ alternative of Java's split(str, -1)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing

In java if I say:

```
String input = "3, 4, 5,,"
String[] s = input.split(",", -1)
```

The output should look like: '3'; ' 4'; ' 5'; ''; ''; Which is 5 symbols length.

Currently from what I see from the Internet the functions usually split up to the '5' [which does what a normal split, without the -1 does] and terminate as they don't think the last comma in the end means a empty character as well as the empty char following it, simply because after the last comma there is no another enclosing coma. Indeed even a space does not work.

Can you please hint me a good tested method which already works or I will have to write my own parser?

Comment: `boost::algorithm::split` is what I usually use. | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435385/split-a-string-using-c11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g ...

Comment: Are you interested in saving the spaces too (5 `string`s:  `"3 ",  "4 ",  "5 ",  "",  ""`)?

Comment: No, the spaces are not important. I will reread again but in the boost library I don't see an analogous version of split(, -1).