# how can i split a vector <string > and acces what i need in it?

Tags: c++, vector

I take the input from text file. Inputs are similar with the example given below.

```
size 5,

turn_count 3,

entity 1 ACDEF 2x2,
 
entity 2 BDFHC 4x5,
 
entity 3 CDHGF 5x5,
 
turn 1 2x3 4x5 5x4,

turn 2 3x3 4x4 5x3,

turn 3 3x4 4x3 5x2.
```

I assign this input line by line into a `vector<string>` by `getline()`. I want to access ACDEF, BDHGF, CDHGF seperately and assign to another vector. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Use something like `std::stringstream` to further split each line into its component words and interpret it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string using C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435385/split-a-string-using-c11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user31264 suggested you could write a split function and split every line you got into its words.

IMHO this is a better and more flexible split function though:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream(str);
    while(std::getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

What that function does is creating a `stringstream` out of your `string` (your line) and extracting words delimited by `char delimiter` by using `getline()` on that stream.

So while reading your file with `getline()` you could pass every line into that split function with

```
auto words = split(line, ' ');
```

and iterate over all words that line contains.

Answer (score 0):

You may use istringstream, or write a simple function:

```
vector<string> Split(const string& s) {
    vector<string> vsWords;
    string sWord;
    for (char c : s) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            vsWords.push_back(sWord);
            sWord.clear();
        }
        else
            sWord += c;
    }
    if (!sWord.empty())
        vsWords.push_back(sWord);
    return vsWords;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With the assumption, `text.txt` looks like you've given:

```
size 5,

turn_count 3,

entity 1 ACDEF 2x2,

entity 2 BDFHC 4x5,

entity 3 CDHGF 5x5,

turn 1 2x3 4x5 5x4,

turn 2 3x3 4x4 5x3,

turn 3 3x4 4x3 5x2.
```

this code snippet should find those token of your interest: `ACDEF`, `BDFHC`, `CDHGF`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line;
    vector<string> vect;

    // result vector with the found string
    vector<string> vectResult;

    // token you want to find
    // can also use array or whatever you like
    const list<string> lst = {"ACDEF","BDFHC","CDHGF"};

    // get your text.txt into a vector
    ifstream myfile ("../src/text.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        while ( getline (myfile, line)){
            vect.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    // constructor for the token iterator
    regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> rend;

    // for every token of interest
    for (string x : lst){   
        // go through my initial vector
        for(string text : vect){
            // extract it from the line, only if it is founded.
            if (regex_search(text, regex(x))){
                regex re(x);
                regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> a ( text.begin(), text.end(), re);
                while (a!=rend)
                    // put the token of interest into the result vector
                    vectResult.push_back(*a++);
            }
        }
    }
    // check content of your new vector
    for (string x: vectResult)
        cout << x << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

usually you'd like to change the regex the way it fits your needs.