# How to extract data from string in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

**Note: I am working using C++11 standard**

I am looking to write a function that handles the following problem:

Given the following input: `a,b,c` I want it to print `a` and `b` and `c`

Given: `a,b,c,` I want it to print `a` and `b` and `c` and `""`

Given: `,a` I want it to print `""` and `a`

Given `,` it should print `""` and in case of empty string it shouldn't print anything

In other words I want to extract every value between two `,` plus to take care of the edges.

---

My current implementation is so buggy and I had edited it more than 8 times since I always find some edge cases.

```
void print(const string &command)
{
        string vertex_title = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < command.lengh()) {
        if (command[i] == ',') {
            if (i==command.lengh()-1) return false;
            std::cout<<vertex_title;
            vertex_title = "";
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        vertex_title += command[i++];
}
```

Note: I don't know but maybe regex help here (I know nothing about it)

Comment: Show a minimal compilable example. What is `splitter_index`? What is `vertex_title`? Explain the problem. What bugs do you find? Also, you should take the argument by `const&` to avoid wasting CPU copying it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string using C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435385/split-a-string-using-c11)

Comment: Not really. What is `lengh()`? Where is the final brace of that `while` loop?

Comment: Construct a `std::istringstream` from that string and then use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline to read fields, with comma as delimiter.

Comment: @bipll are you sure you got me the correct link? getline won't split string

Comment: You can use [boost::algorithm::split](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split.html) or [std::strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: @daniel It will read until the specified delimiter, and extract until there, so you can call it again to get the next field.

Comment: @daniel A function with the return type void may not have a return statement with a non-void expression like return false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could implement such a function, I'd strongly suggest using existing solutions. There are quite a few.

I'm personally used to `absl::StrSplit()` (see https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/strings) which by default will do what you want.

Thomas Sablik also wrote in a comment:

> You can use boost::algorithm::split or std::strtok

Comment: 100% do not use `strtok()` or other leftover C bits. And there is already a way to do this without pulling in any external library.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this. Even though it's ugly. You can run and debug it step by step.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void print(const string &command)
{
    std::string vertex_title = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < command.size()) {
        if (command[i] == ',') {
            cout << vertex_title;
            vertex_title = "";
        }
        else {
            vertex_title += command[i];
        }
        ++i;

        if (i == command.size())
            cout << vertex_title;
    }
}

int main()
{
    print("a,b,c");
    print("a,b,c,");
    print(",a");
    print(",");

    return 0;
}
```