# Extracting tokens from string in C++

Tags: c++, regex, string

**Edit: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use regex since it seems buggy and not trustable**

I had the following function which extracts tokens of a string whenever one the following symbols is found: `+,-,^,*,!`

```
bool extract_tokens(string expression, std::vector<string> &tokens) {    
    static const std::regex reg(R"(\+|\^|-|\*|!|\(|\)|([\w|\s]+))");
    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(right_token.begin(), right_token.end(), reg, 0),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::back_inserter(tokens));
    return true;
}
```

I though it worked perfectly until today I found an edge case,
The following input : !aaa + ! a is supposed to return `!,aaa ,+,!, a` But it returns `!,aaa ,+,"",!, a` Notice the extra empty string between + and !.

How may I prevent this behaviour? I think this can be done with the regex expression,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219474/discussion-on-question-by-dure-extracting-tokens-from-string-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to salvage the regular expression-based solution, I came up with this:

```
[-+^*!()]|\s*[^-+^*!()\s][^-+^*!()]*
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cf4qEM). This reports delimiters, and anything between delimiters including leading and trailing whitespace, but drops tokens consisting of whitespace alone.

---

A similar expression that also strips leading and trailing whitespace:

```
[-+^*!()]|[^-+^*!()\s]+(\s+[^-+^*!()\s]+)*)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TjzKoa)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436872/4645334 you could solve the problem with:

```
bool extract_tokens(std::string expression, std::vector<std::string> &tokens) {
  std::string token;

  for (const auto& c: expression) {
    if (c == '/' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '+' || c == '!') {
      if (token.length() && !std::all_of(token.cbegin(), token.cend(), [](auto c) { return c == ' '; })) tokens.push_back(token);
      token.clear();
      tokens.emplace_back(1, c);
    } else {
      token += c;
    }
  }

  if (token.length() && !std::all_of(token.cbegin(), token.cend(), [](auto c) { return c == ' '; })) tokens.push_back(token);
     
  return true;
}
```

Input:

```
"!aaa + ! a"
```

Output:

```
"!","aaa ","+","!"," a"
```

Comment: `std::string(c, 1)` wouldn't compile. You probably meant `tokens.push_back(c)`. Anyway, this has the same problem as the original question - it produces tokens that consist of whitespace alone. The OP wants  `! +` to be split into two tokens `!` and `+`, not three tokens.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `c` is a char. `tokens.push_back(c)` wouldn't compile: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cx8csmVomCMroaiy

Comment: Ah, sorry. I confused `token` and `tokens`. Still, to construct a string of one character, it should be `std::string(1, c)`. You have your arguments the wrong way round.