# How to match \n in regex but skip n from following text?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the numerical data from the mentioned string, however, when using the given pattern, I also miss out on the following string.

pattern : `[^\\n)]+`

```
409416,-15.84361,-22.66174,-15.777729,-11.565274,0.184927,2.184308,-2.918847,-1.438143,-1.832789,-2.392894,-2.936923,-1.699626,-1.699626,-0.559298,-0.559298,-0.559298,-0.559298,-0.559298\n0.268223,0.088596,-0.953149,-1.344175,0.197503,4.143355,3.463934,0.289587,-0.063034,0.35563,2.322007,-13.589606,-11.883781,17.186039,-7.376517,10.132304,-4.420093,0.77321,5.358715,3.092631,0.457418,1.67359,4.545597,1.758356,1.758356,0.544843,0.544843,0.544843,0.544843,0.544843\n-4.421537,-2.864239,-3.992804,-2.769629,-0.345838,1.462282,-0.733731,-1.554252,0.376582,5.262342,7.720245,-14.295092,-14.852295,-16.991022,15.644931,14.116446,-4.67732,-6.69726,-0.406152,1.403272,-1.297639,-2.341637,-1.378868,-2.402558,-2.402558,-3.345482,-3.345482,-3.345482,-3.345482,-3.345482\n0.303624,-1.55541,-1.163894,-0.002663,1.203844,0.47408,-1.725865,-1.635311,-0.809665,1.496815,0.127842,2.615432,1.528776,-34.86355,4.610298,1.973559,-2.828502,1.598024,1.195854,0.623229,-1.526112,-0.921527,-0.346238,-0.905547,-0.905547,0.348902,0.348902,0.348902,0.348902,0.348902\n0.03196,-1.725865,-1.523449,-1.086656,-0.183773,0.516694,0.561972,0.292971,-0.183773,-0.002663,-2.048133,-13.026555,-17.415792,29.832436,3.382483,2.988304,-1.811093,0.114525,0.386189,-0.628556,-1.704558,-1.853707,-1.222488,-1.182537,-1.182537,-0.255684,-0.255684,-0.255684,-0.255684,-0.255684\n0.287644,-1.054696,-1.134597,-0.761725,0.109198,0.242367,-0.415486,-0.191763,-0.514031,0.138495,0.596595,4.54904,-4.29602,5.593082,7.870266,2.460956,1.787123,0.70313,-0.258347,0.103872,-0.26101,-0.058594,0.189099,0.713784,0.713784,-0.114525,-0.114525,-0.114525,-0.114525,-0.114525',Badminton_Smash
```

Required: string without `\n`.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/sMtFzd/1

Comment: Please reduce your example to the smallest length that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use splitting with

```py
\\n|\)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fbeh1c/2).

C++ supports splitting, see [Split a string using C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435385/split-a-string-using-c11).

Use

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> split(const string& input, const string& regex) {
    // passing -1 as the submatch index parameter performs splitting
    std::regex re(regex);
    std::sregex_token_iterator
        first{input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1},
        last;
    return {first, last};
}
    
int main() {
    std::string input("409416,-15.84361,-22.66174,-15.777729,-11.565274,0.184927,2.184308,-2.918847,-1.438143,-1.832789,-2.392894,-2.936923,-1.699626,-1.699626,-0.559298,-0.559298,-0.559298,-0.559298,-0.559298\n0.268223,0.088596,-0.953149,-1.344175,0.197503,4.143355,3.463934,0.289587,-0.063034,0.35563,2.322007,-13.589606,-11.883781,17.186039,-7.376517,10.132304,-4.420093,0.77321,5.358715,3.092631,0.457418,1.67359,4.545597,1.758356,1.758356,0.544843,0.544843,0.544843,0.544843,0.544843\n-4.421537,-2.864239,-3.992804,-2.769629,-0.345838,1.462282,-0.733731,-1.554252,0.376582,5.262342,7.720245,-14.295092,-14.852295,-16.991022,15.644931,14.116446,-4.67732,-6.69726,-0.406152,1.403272,-1.297639,-2.341637,-1.378868,-2.402558,-2.402558,-3.345482,-3.345482,-3.345482,-3.345482,-3.345482\n0.303624,-1.55541,-1.163894,-0.002663,1.203844,0.47408,-1.725865,-1.635311,-0.809665,1.496815,0.127842,2.615432,1.528776,-34.86355,4.610298,1.973559,-2.828502,1.598024,1.195854,0.623229,-1.526112,-0.921527,-0.346238,-0.905547,-0.905547,0.348902,0.348902,0.348902,0.348902,0.348902\n0.03196,-1.725865,-1.523449,-1.086656,-0.183773,0.516694,0.561972,0.292971,-0.183773,-0.002663,-2.048133,-13.026555,-17.415792,29.832436,3.382483,2.988304,-1.811093,0.114525,0.386189,-0.628556,-1.704558,-1.853707,-1.222488,-1.182537,-1.182537,-0.255684,-0.255684,-0.255684,-0.255684,-0.255684\n0.287644,-1.054696,-1.134597,-0.761725,0.109198,0.242367,-0.415486,-0.191763,-0.514031,0.138495,0.596595,4.54904,-4.29602,5.593082,7.870266,2.460956,1.787123,0.70313,-0.258347,0.103872,-0.26101,-0.058594,0.189099,0.713784,0.713784,-0.114525,-0.114525,-0.114525,-0.114525,-0.114525',Badminton_Smash");
    std::string rgx("\\\\n|\\)");
    for (auto const c : split(input, rgx)) {
        std::cout << c << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [C++ proof](https://tio.run/##jVVNbyM3DD2vf8UgBVoHGGtFitRHEuTQv9CrgWDWmU2MxmPDMy4CpPnt6RMn3SQ3z8GgRemJfHykNofD6mGzeXv7bTtsnk73fXOz3Y/Tse92t4uPtWP/0D/fLk7jdnhohm7Xj4du0zfjdH@9WOD36uqffjPtjzdm4zz23Tbj4Wk7LTf7YZyaee33ZjscTlPbfF00@MvmZdHg@/69OXSj3bSiphub6RE3nX7sumnziPP3/TM2HBHE1B@bQ3/8uT/uxvmyCacMxOIwWIAvZ/zrD89oK3fT/u9@uNsCp0Pw5q7fz@1xnF4sUvejf9gOy8t2Dtz1w339c@xbBPfa/jry1I3TjH/sp9NxaF4MpDXH6/XidfFtsR2mZtdVNGT67RNTM/byQnwRiu2K1GUJkdoVs4uRkthawscFJjmNylj1jrIUTi1XI/iME65QzpKwzUnIJKFaOXDKpXpD4VzE9oVY2LyxlMjxs@WdauGSz7XWg3ccMwPPO5@zFgMpGkhqxC6IUNIacEnqQysOkQXVNjiJoYSaCwLTnOo5H4O3JeyIAdkFZu9rTsFpLtFHYyHnkDK1lJB99AEXJRdSVEot4abAwSNTcYLDpUaWUmBqFbA5Ub3bF46B4BFNQrkFAyloQXgqyAw4LmkOGj8MpCwCss8x1oPdThpSZTxH4RplcAVV8FaFFMF4qUkHwQU1BInMmetSCiEhPPCnKqxcGUF@cCro5iDcJpfYsyg2ieOiyMjMrIx/MCMuI8/cQkFRpAAPbiLYsZITKyntKqL2aS69@Ei4C4F4yKbCATjFMOsHCg2mLnCfoylOPKt@sULNRmoS51lVPyh5ZJmTVbGscZWJFYrwHKEEROJDlioNSVL1jrqw5qim3gC9Ud2efYlYQwolZjLdoQFAF/qJVELNTjmnhIQDyIpViuACRJVaggIVqOWbOau37SWDZxgElWqNAAVg60dARSKrWEGxOc3lhN9apHjkkz5Z1ZmL53OMyowPVOLXVBXFnzvLZ2RqdSO0QzLxUYylRqgR7VaxGE2a6NOmD0qRo5dMIVh3YQ3sw0xOSBPExKVOD4wjtEvILLn2Y0HreatVJpp7i0iUK9MhR8qm6AjudA7ci@kC@9EL1smOGWC2Rpl11tT/FiLGySznWjZ/coKmjRKVOBNGkFcxvIQxauEhXEKNsR/NGM2HTCXPFBZK0dhRgvrrZCDordSDmGla1EZDmecKYxLVVtSC0VtbMafKKfiR6Ms8NDBobCgmoIU54BxMAwQlJxMN1OOtOB7KKvNYL76UeozQZvJhrH4Rfab1R/tnd7/D07Mf7v7adePjBd7BL4/P8eF5ebHGN/y7Xl@aGy9qs@xO0/79nd40V@@P@fvzjTOX9orNSJv9aWpubrAPPxfr4QIYePHen0KP5@/t7T8).

Comment: I need string-match 'without' \n, actually, I'm using C++ for the cleaning. Regex website is for generating correct regex.

Comment: @BhaskarDhariyal Just found a question with C++ regex splitting code. Kindly check update.