# Regex Complilation Errors in c++

Tags: c++, regex, compilation, undefined-reference

I am working on a project with someone and we have the exact same code however his code compiles while mine continues to throw an error. Here is my code:

```
bool r_parser::parseMake(string name, string command, string type, string val)
{
    regex regName("^\\w+$");
    if(std::regex_match(name, regName) == true)
    {
        cout << "We have a match!" << endl;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here are the errors I am getting:

```
'undefined reference to std::basic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_compile()'

'undefined reference to bool std::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<std::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, char, std::regex_traits<char> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<std::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, std::basic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> > const&, std::bitset<11u>)'
```

Since my partner's code compiled and we couldn't find anything different about my code I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this situation.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I have:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

in my header file.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? Not all compiler versions support std::regex.

Comment: for starters, your snippet is missing `#inlcude <regex>`. It's also missing `#inlcude <string>`, `#inlcude <iostream>`, and `using namespace std`, all of which are needed for that function to compile.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I had those included in my header file. I added that to the main post.

I am running gcc 4.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more research, Michael, and it would appear that `#include <regex>` is [only a placeholder until GCC version 4.9.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8913707/472647)

If you're on a Windows system (which I seem to remember you are), you're using GCC via MinGW, so you'll need to update to the latest version manually. I'm on 4.9.1, and that's why it works for me. [You can download that from Sourceforge.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.0/)

If you're on Linux, you should be able to update gcc and g++ via the repositories.

If you don't want to update, you can also use [the Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html). However, I recommend updating your compiler, mainly because it is just a generally good idea to be using the latest version of whatever compiler you're implementing, unless you have an explicit reason not to.

Sorry I couldn't answer that earlier, but I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows following code works to remove Regex Complilation Errors.

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: this is the best answer for Ubuntu users as well. Some software relies on <tr1/regex> when the best solution is to use <regex> because it is now a part of the standard. This problem is misleading because /tr1 and /tr2 are both included in the upgrade utilities for gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using g++ as compiler. As it would not require to link libstdc++ explicitly. 
Whereas gcc, requires one to explicitly link libstdc++.